# SailsJS : Redirecting to controller action with variables

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

I am using sailsJS with ejs engine and i want to redirect the user back to the input page with messages ( validation errors ... ) .
i used to use this easily with laravel in PHP (  return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!'); )

i.e : i need to redirect the user back saying that this site dont exist

```
find : function(req,res){
    var id = req.param(íd');
    Site.find(id).where({isDeleted : null })
    .exec(function(err,siteFound){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        if(siteFound) {
            return res.view('site/show', {
                site : siteFound
            });
        } else {
             return res.redirect('/site');
          }
    })
},
```

i searched in sails documentation but found nothing. how can this be performed in SailsJS ?

thanks

UPDATE : i found what i needed exactly by installing `sails-hook-flash` . the feature i needed is called `flash messages`. 
Thank you for your help !

> Blockquote

Comment: Do you want to use the `status` variable in a sails view / ejs template?

Comment: i want to be able to pass custom messages that i will display in the redirected view

Answer (score 3):

I can't quite tell if you want a true browser redirect. A browser redirect means sending a message back to the browser that says "use this other url instead", and then it gets fresh data (meaning new `req` and `res` objects) from your app. If this is what you want, I'd say the only real options for passing data are query strings, like:

```
return res.redirect('/site?message=notfound');
```

Then in your recieving controller action for site you can access this via `req.param('message')`.

---

However, if you just want to return the appropriate content *now* without getting the browser to redirect, you can just call whatever view or controller action you like:

```
if(siteFound) {
    return res.view('site/show', {
        site : siteFound
    });
} else {
    // uncomment one of the options:

    // ONE: return another view
    // return res.view('site/notfound, {requested: id});

    // TWO: pass to another controller action in same controller
    // req.options.message = 'not found';
    // return module.exports.someOtherAction(req, res);

    // THREE: pass to a controller action in another controller
    // req.options.message = 'not found';
    // var OtherController = require('./OtherController');
    // return OtherController.someOtherAction(req, res);
}
```

Any of those three options will keep you at the user's requested url ("/site/abc123" or whatever), but display the content you specify.

Answer (score 0):

`res.notfound("my message string");` should do it right?
You can work with `res.json()` if it is an ajax request expecting a custom response.
Read the docs about the `res` object [HERE](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res) and the custom `notfound` response [HERE](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-not-found).